# Start Activity + background image Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, titanium-mobile

I am creating an iPhone/Android app in Titanium. I have 2 js files
1. app.js   2.rss.js

In app.js i have written the following code :-

```
      if(Titanium.Platform.name != 'android'){
    var rssWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow(
        {
            url : "rss.js",
            title : "RSS FEEDS",
            barColor:'#0f0f0f',
            backgroundImage:'images/Background.png'
        });
    navigation.open(rssWindow,{animated:true});
  }
  else{
    var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
            url: 'rss.js',
    });
    intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

This code takes me to rss.js correctly but in rss.js when i try to set the background image of the current window, the app crashes while running in Android whereas it runs correctly in Iphone.

rss.js

```
      if(Titanium.Platform.name == 'android')
          var activity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
      var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
      Titanium.API.info('RSS screen loaded');
      win.backgroundImage = 'images/Background.png'
```

Does anyone has a solution to this problem or am i doing something wrong.
Image path has been checked and its correct.

Comment: What Ti SDK version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't checked my application on i-phone but yes, i was facing similar unexpected closing problem in my app too..

And the problem is related to setting background property of Window in Titanium..
This property works fine up to `titanium sdk 1.7.5 *`

but after that it crashes.

I just tired a trick to work around setting the image as background..

Just created the View

```
var WindowBackground = Ti.UI.createView({

         backgroundImage:'../../Images/General/SelectedimageforBackground.png'

    });
```

and added this to window before all my controls, that are to be displayed on window.
and the result looks the same as what was required..

```
* you can check the sdk in your Tiapp.xml
```